# Correct path to save file in Android

Tags: android, android-file

I'm trying to write an app for Android and I need to save the resposne from a server, I managed to do it by saving it in a txt file in this path:

`String path= "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.simone.pizzino/files/response.txt";
final File file = new File(path);`

Testing it on my friend's phone he can't see the folder at that path, his path is something like `data/data/"packageName"`, it doesnt work on the emulator in Android Studio either. 
My phone is a Nexus 5X running 7.1 stock rom.
My friend is rooted using 6.1. 
Is there some way to get a dynamic path to the application folder without having to state it as a constant?

Sorry if this question was already asked but I counldn't find a solution for my problem.

Comment: I am uncertain what you consider "the application folder" to be. Your hardcoded path most closely resembles the output of `getExtenalFilesDir(null)`, called on a `Context` (e.g., an `Activity` or `Service`). Beyond that, please explain **in detail** what "it doesn't work" means.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using the hardcoded path? you can simply save the file in the internal storage https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: The directory of his application is different than mine, his is something like data/data/packageName. The application can't save the file in that location since it cant find it.

Comment: @petrumo because it's my first time programming in android and I don't know how to do stuff, I'm still learning

Comment: np, the question was meant to consider the approach and to point it to the right direction

Answer (score 5):

First thing you have to do is to add permission to access external storage in your manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Save a File on Internal Storage

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
 outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
 outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}

public File getTempFile(Context context, String url) {
   File file;
try {
    String fileName = Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment();
    file = File.createTempFile(fileName, null, context.getCacheDir());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Error while creating file
}
return file;
}
```

Save a File on External Storage

```
/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    return true;
}
return false;
}

/* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
    Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    return true;
}
return false;
}

public File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
// Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
if (!file.mkdirs()) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Directory not created");
}
return file;
}
```

Comment: On Android 6 and newer the permissions model has changed.